# how to prevent special characters at generating a token in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i generate a token which converts the datetime in bytes.
Here is how i generate the token:

```
public string generateToken()
    {
        byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
        byte[] key = new Guid().ToByteArray();
        string token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());
        return token;
    }
```

This is how it looks like when the token is generated:

> chas42Sbo9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

but on some days it generates special characters,too. like in this example:

> chs2BiT/z0gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

i parse the result in a link to redirect to another page

> http://test.com/abo.aspx?chas42Sbo9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

with the special characters it looks like this:

> http://test.com/abo.aspx?chs2BiT/z0gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

and this doesnt work.

is it possible to generate a token but without special characters?

Comment: Is it possible to use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` to convert the slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `Base64` is defined:

> The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase
>   characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the
>   numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless
>   character, "=", is used for trailing padding.

So you can't use `Convert.ToBase64String` if you don't want `/` character to appear in your token.

Comment: Why don't just use just GUID? Is current date important in your Token?

Comment: i need to check if the token is 24 hours old.

Comment: So you should save that generated GUID with creation date somewhere. With your current solution user can manipulate the Token and change expiration date.